# How to <move selected jpeg image file> with the help of JFileChooser to a selected folder in java swing?

Tags: java, file-io

In java swong , Using JFileChooser,i want to select an image and move the selected image to a desired folder.

But dont know how to move?

---

**Update**: this is what I did

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    imageFileChooser.setVisible(true); 
    int checkIfOpened = imageFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this); 
    if (checkIfOpened == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
        File file = imageFileChooser.getSelectedFile(); 
        // int size = file.getLength(); 
        // don't know what to do here
    }else{ 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`File#renameTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29).

```
File file = imageFileChooser.getSelectedFile(); 
File destination = new File("/path/to/new/location", file.getName());
boolean success = file.renameTo(destination);
// You might want to check success result here.
```

Comment: It would be good to mention that behavior of renameTo() is platform-dependent, and most probably will not work if the destination is on a different partition.

Comment: It's at least faster. You could also combine both. If `renameTo()` returns `false`, then try it by streaming.

Answer (score 2):

JFileChooser has a getSelectedFile() method, use that, then open a FileInputStream with that file. Then create a FileOutputStream with the desired destination. Then you can get FileChannels and use the [transferTo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo%28long,%20long,%20java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel%29) method:

```
int size = file.getLength();
fileInputStream.getChannel().transferTo(0, size, fileOutputStream.getChannel());
fileOutputStream.close();
file.delete();
```